# i want a java editor with embedded compiler and work under linux and did not require a a big amount of ram

Tags: java, compiler-construction, editor

I want a Java IDE with a compiler for Linux and that does not require a a big amount of RAM.
I have 256 MB of ram, so my options are limited

Comment: edited for clarity. I think that's what you meant. Or were you trying to ask about java for embedded systems?

Answer (score 1):

In my first programming courses, we used [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org) as our "IDE". Really basic, yet gets the job done. It honestly don't have a lot of features, but it's lightweight, portable and effective
You have to link it with an external compiler though, but it shouldn't be a problem if you already develop in Java with this computer.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse would be the last thing you want. I can gather you've probably already tried it from the title. For a small footprint I'd suggest JEdit. It's much smaller, mature and extensible. There's also Kate if you run KDE. While it doesn't have the embedded compiler support you could add one in as an external command.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "IDE".

You could use Emacs with that kind of memory foootprint, use Ant for the builds and emacs would allow you to debug in the editor, and also take you to compile errors...

But it would not have a GUI development component.

For more detail on using Emacs as a full featured Java IDE, read this IBM document:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-emacs/

Answer (score 0):

Does the 256MB of RAM also include program space, or will the code be stored elsewhere in flash or another memory type?

You can get embeddable java machines, and small java compilers for linux.  The IDE, however, is tricky as you don't merely say editor, but you want a whole integrated environment.

Since you have Java installed already, I suggest Eclipse.  It seems bulky and resource intensive on PCs, but you can cut it back significantly by removing features (classes) you don't want/need.

-Adam

Comment: Eclipse for this will be very, very slow as the machine would swap to death.

Answer (score 0):

jEdit will work easily.

Eclipse 1.x will work in that amount of RAM. Depending on your version of java, Eclipse 1.x will definitely work in that RAM.